# Как привязать к рубрикам записей wordpress определенный шаблон страницы?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на wordpress в котором есть записи принадлежащие определенной (рубрике) категории. Если перейти по ссылке этой рубрики, то видим заголовок "archive for category.." и вывод на ней анонсов статей в том виде, котором меня не устраивает. Мне нужен вывод в виде аля шаблон "blog", который можно настроить только для страниц. Вопрос: как привязать определенный шаблон к рубрике и сделать правильно, чтобы было универсально для любой рубрики?

Итак, что делал и что получилось: нашел шаблон страницы блога, переименовал его в category-ярлык-рубрики.php и закинул в дочернюю тему (все манипуляции проделываю через нее), добавил папку с форматами записей по пути. Шаблон подтянулся, но возникло 2 проблемы на данный момент: выводятся сразу все статьи, а не конкретной рубрики, для формата записи галерея выводится пустой слайдер - как решить?

код category-ярлык-рубрики.php:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="core">
  <div id="content">
          <ul class="medpost">    
                    <?php
            if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
              $paged = get_query_var('paged');
            } else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {
              $paged = get_query_var('page');
            } else {
              $paged = 1;
            }
            query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'paged' => $paged ) );
          ?>
          <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php if(has_post_format('gallery'))  {
                            echo get_template_part( '/includes/post-types/medpost' );
                        }elseif(has_post_format('video')){
                            echo get_template_part( '/includes/post-types/medpost' );
                        }elseif(has_post_format('audio')){
                            echo get_template_part( '/includes/post-types/medpost' );
                        }elseif(has_post_format('image')){
                            echo get_template_part( '/includes/post-types/image' );
                        }elseif(has_post_format('link')){
                            echo get_template_part( '/includes/post-types/link' );
                        }elseif(has_post_format('quote')){
                            echo get_template_part( '/includes/post-types/quote' );
                            } else {
                            echo get_template_part( '/includes/post-types/medpost' );
                        }?>                   
          <?php endwhile; ?><!-- end post -->                   
            </ul><!-- end latest posts section-->          
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
          <div class="pagination"><?php pagination('&laquo;', '&raquo;'); ?></div>
          <?php else : ?>
                        <h1>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</h1>
                        <?php get_search_form(); ?><br/>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- end #core .eightcol--> 
        <div id="sidebar">     
                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>      
        </div>        
    <div id="core_bg"></div>
</div><!-- #core -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

код формата галереи gallery-slider.php:

```
<div class="flexslider postslider" style="max-height:365px; padding-bottom:0; overflow:hidden">
        <ul class="slides">
      <?php    
        $args = array(
                    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
                    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                    'post_status' => null,
                    'posts_per_page' => -1
        );          
        $attachments = get_posts( $args );
         if ( $attachments ) {
          foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
             echo '<li>';
             echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'format-standard');
             echo '</li>';
            }
         }
             ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если уж вы делаете `query_posts()` в шаблоне рубрики, то добавляйте в него параметр `cat` или `category_name`. По сути вы переопределяете стандартный для этой страницы запрос и формируете свой, затем выводите записи, попавшие в вашу выборку. Т. к. ограничений по категории у вас нет - выводиться будут все записи типа `post` с соответствующей страницы пагинации (`paged`). Сделайте, например, так:

```
$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'cat' => $cat_id
    )
);
```